# Cardinality of Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition:** $\beta X$ is the Stone-Čech compactification of $X$.

> **Theorem A:** If $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $f\colon X \to K$ is
> continuous, there is a continuous $F: \beta X \to K$ such that $F \circ e = f$, where $e\colon X\to\beta X$ is an embedding into a compact Hausdorff space.

> Show that $\left|\beta\mathbb{N}\right|\geq\left|\beta\mathbb{Q}\right|$.

Let $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be a bijection. As *any* function from the discrete topology is continuous ($\mathbb{N}$ with the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}_\text{std.}$ is the discrete topology), we can enlarge the range. Therefore, we can enlarge the range to $\beta\mathbb{Q}$, which is a compact Hausdorff space, so that $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{Q}$ is continous. By **Theorem A** we can extend $f$ uniquely to to a continuous function
$\beta f\colon\beta\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{Q}$.

I need to show that
$\beta f\colon\beta\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{Q}$ is surjective, i.e. $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]=\beta\mathbb{Q}$. As for any mapping $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]\subseteq\beta\mathbb{Q}$, it's enough to show that $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]\supseteq\beta\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\beta f[\beta \Bbb N]$ is compact, so closed, but also dense as it contains the dense set $\Bbb Q = f[\Bbb N]$. So it must be the whole image.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Could you explain why $f[\mathbb{N}]\subseteq\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$?

Comment: Because $\beta f[\Bbb N] = f[\Bbb N]$ as $\beta f$ extends $f$. I'm ignoring the embeddings for convenience.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I understand that but not where the $\beta\mathbb{N}$ comes in...

Comment: $\Bbb N \subseteq \beta \Bbb N$, so this holds for the images under $\beta f$ too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I see. So for Stone-Čech compactifications $X\subseteq\beta X$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122442/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-d-math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof looks correct, you just need a little push.

We will use the following result:

**Lemma:** If $X$ is a topological space, $D$ is a dense subset of $X$ and $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ such that $D\subseteq A$, then we have the equality $A=X$.

Since $\beta f$ extends the bijective function $f$, we get the relations $$\mathbb{Q}=f[\mathbb{N}] \subseteq \beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}].$$

Now, since $\beta f$ is continuous, this tells us that $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$ is a compact space (therefore, a closed subset of $\beta\mathbb{Q}$) that contains a dense subset of $\beta\mathbb{Q}$. So, if we let $X=\beta\mathbb{Q}$, $D=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$, then we can apply the lemma to get that  $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$ must be exactly $\beta\mathbb{Q}$; in other words, $\beta f$ is surjective.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb{Q}=f[\mathbb{N}]$ do you instead mean $\beta\mathbb{Q}=f[\mathbb{N}]$? So that $\beta\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$?

Comment: $f$ is a bijective function between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$; in particular, it is surjective. This tells us that the image of $f$ is precisely it's codomain, in this case, $f[\mathbb{N}]=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that I am identifying $\mathbb{Q}$ with its image under the natural embedding. If you want, I can edit the answer with the embeddings into $\beta\mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Let me edit my post and explain where I'm at and getting lost.

Comment: Does the first edit look correct?

Comment: Yes. What I'm trying to explain is how to get the other inclusion. Let me edit a lemma into my answer and hopefully it will clear things up.

Comment: Okay, sure. I do understand that as $\beta f$ is continous and $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is compact, its image $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$ is compact. Also, I know that $\beta f[\beta\mathbb{N}]$ being a compact subspace of the compact Hausdorff space $\beta\mathbb{Q}$, it is closed.

Comment: @D.Math: And $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\beta\Bbb Q$ and hence also in $\beta f[\beta\Bbb N]$, so $\beta f[\beta\Bbb N]\supseteq\operatorname{cl}_{\beta\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q=\operatorname{cl}_{\beta\Bbb Q}f[\Bbb N]$.

Comment: What about now? Is it easier to understand?

Comment: Yes! I wasn't aware of such lemma, unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more precise:

Let $(e_1, \beta \Bbb N)$ be the Stone-Čech compactification of $\Bbb N$, and $(e_2, \beta \Bbb Q)$ that of $\Bbb Q$.

So indeed take any bijection $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$. This is trivially continuous and indeed $f':\Bbb N \to \beta \Bbb Q$ given by $f' = e_2 \circ f$ is also continuous.
Note that $f'[\Bbb N] = e_2[\Bbb Q]$ which is by definition (of compactification) a dense subspace of $\Bbb Q$.

So Thm A gives us $\beta f': \beta \Bbb N \to \beta \Bbb Q$ so that $$\beta f' \circ e_1 =f'$$
as functions on $\Bbb N$.

Now consider $\beta f' [\beta \Bbb N]$. It is compact so closed in the Hausdorff space $\beta \Bbb Q$. On the other hand, applying what we know so far:

$$\beta f'[e_1[\Bbb N]] = f'[\Bbb N] = e_2[f[\Bbb N]] = e_2[\Bbb Q]$$

we get that $\beta f'[\beta \Bbb N]$ contains the dense set $e_2[\Bbb Q]$. And the only set that is closed *and* dense (in $\beta \Bbb Q$) is $\beta \Bbb Q$. It follows that $\beta f'$ is onto and so $|\beta \Bbb Q| \le |\beta\Bbb N|$.

---

It's easier to "think of" $\beta \Bbb Q$ and $\beta \Bbb N$ as supersets of $\Bbb N$ resp. $\Bbb Q$, and theorem A being about "real" extension: and then the proof would just be: $f$, the bijection, which is then indeed "the same" as $f: \Bbb N \to \beta \Bbb Q$ (codomain extension) and $\beta f : \beta \Bbb N \to \beta \Bbb Q$ a real extension and then $\Bbb N$ is dense in $\beta \Bbb N$ and $\beta f[\Bbb N] = \Bbb Q$ is then dense and the same argument applies ($\beta f[\beta \Bbb N]$ being closed and dense). But here we have to more precise than that in the actual proof, as I gave above, which uses the embeddings and definitions of a compactification. But the idea is easier to grasp in such a concrete "subspaces setting", as it were.

Comment: Should $f’$ be mapping into $\beta\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: This post is in a way a hommage to professor Maurice (RIP) who taught us students to be very precise (he taught the compactifications part of the curriculum).

Comment: This is *very* precise! Thank you for this post, it’s cleared up a lot for me.

Comment: @D.Math You're welcome.

Comment: It's also not too hard to construct a continuous and surjective $g: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$ and the essentially same proof would then give: $|\beta \Bbb N | \le |\beta \Bbb  Q|$. So both spaces have the same (huge) size: $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. Or use that $\Bbb N$ is $C^\ast$-embedded into $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach which doesn't give an explicit bijection is to use the characterization of $\beta\Bbb N$ as the space of ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$, which are $2^{2^{|\Bbb N|}}$, together with the fact that $\beta\Bbb Q$ is a separable Hausdorff space, hence has also cardinality at most $2^{2^{|\Bbb Q|}}$.